# how to use asyncTask in android

Tags: android

I am new to android.. I was trying to solve an networkonmainthreadexception, so I used async task  but am still getting the same exception.. what is wrong?? 
this is my onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Connection().execute();       
}
```

This is my connection method

```
private class Connection extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        preExecuteLogin();
      }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doInBackgroundLogin();
        return null;
    }


}
```

this is the pre execute method

```
 public void preExecuteLogin()
{
    txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    buttonLogin=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
}
```

and this is my doInBackgroundLogin method

```
 public void doInBackgroundLogin()
{

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
                showToast("Login successfull");

                String link = "http://www.quinoid.com/project/AndroidXml/Login.php?username="
                               + txtUserName.getText().toString() + "&password=" + txtPassword.getText().toString();
                try {

                        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(link);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondpage.class);
                startActivity(myIntent); 
               } else{
                showToast("Invalid Login");
               }

        }
    });       
}
```

so what exactly am I doing wrong?
my stack trace

```
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324): Process: com.example.qwedd, PID: 1324
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at com.example.connection.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at com.example.qwedd.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-11 03:17:38.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1324):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 03:22:38.957: I/Process(1324): Sending signal. PID: 1324 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you please provide your stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are

calling

`Toast.makeText` in the `login()` method.

Toast can only be show on UI thread.

either remove the `Toast` from the `login()` method.

or Call Toast like this

```
private void showToast(String msg){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
    }); 
}
```

**Complete Solution**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    buttonLogin=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Connection().execute();   
        }
    });              
}

public void doInBackgroundLogin() {
    if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
        showToast("Login successfull");

        String link = "http://www.quinoid.com/project/AndroidXml/Login.php?username="
                               + txtUserName.getText().toString() + "&password=" + txtPassword.getText().toString();
        try {    
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(link);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondpage.class);
        startActivity(myIntent); 
    } else{
        showToast("Invalid Login");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you are calling web request in `setOnClickListener` that is on main UI thread. Change code like my edit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make network operations in your main UI, because that would block your program execution with a very disgusting experience for your users. For this, you have to separate network operations inside a `Thread`, or even better, an `AsyncTask` if you're just starting with the thread world.

This is the structure you would use:

```
final class MyNetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Void> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute(final Void param) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(final URL... args) {
    ...
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final Void param) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Even the method names are very self explanatory. When you define your AsyncTask, and call `.execute(url_object)` on it, the first called method will be `.onPreExecute()`, there you may initialize variables and prepare everything for the network operation you want to do. The *hard* part of your network operation should be done inside `doInBackground()`. There you connect, do the data transfer and disconnect from the host. Finally, `onPostExecute()` is called: Once you're done, you can process here your results (transfer it to the main Activity, show a Dialog, etc.).

For more on AsyncTasks (and know what does those parameters mean) I strongly recommend reading the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

A very good example might be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

put the login code itself in the doInBackgroung();
and you should not mix UI with the network , onClick is Ui function,, if u can call it befor executing 
the Asynck, and put the collected data in static members and then run Asynck. and use the these data from the doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are getting input from user in login method that mean you are getting input in doinbackground methods i.e performing ui operation in doinbackground. android says `you cannot perform ui operation in doinbackground method`.

So my advice is get user input in onPreexecute and then login user in the doInbackground method.

or simply invoke your asyntask on your button click, after getting input from user.

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, your code crashed at the line

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(link);
```

This line should be executed in worker thread, not main thread(NetworkOnMainThreadException), because it may take too much time to block UI. The listener `buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` is executed in main thread.
So the solution could be you move the listener code out of the AsyncTask, and trigger the AsyncTask by the listener. Then put the JSON code in the `doInBackground`.

```
@Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(link);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Your asyncTask class on button click.

**and don't update your main ui from background.**

update your ui in **postexecute** or use **runonuithread** for this